# How to use MongoDB C# Driver without specifying a class

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I am using MongoDB c# driver 2.0. I a trying to get a collection without specifying a type or class. Observe:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Core;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
using MongoDB.Shared;

namespace Meshplex.Service.DataWarehouse
{
    public class ProfileControllerMongoDB
    {
        private IMongoDatabase _mongoDb;
        private IMongoCollection _myCollection;
        //private IMongoCollection<ClassHere> _myCollection;

        public ProfileDataControllerMongoDB()
        {
            _mongoDb = GetMongoDatabase();
            _myCollection = _mongoDb.GetCollection(GetCollectionName());
            //_myCollection = _mongoDb.GetCollection<ClassHere>("Collection");
        }

        public async Task<string> GetAllRecords()
        {
            //This should return json
            return await _myCollection.Find(new BsonDocument());
        }
```

As you see I should be specifying a class when declaring `IMongoCollection`. Is there a way to use MongoDB Driver without specifying a a class?

Comment: Have you tried using <dynamic> in there? See http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/what_is_new/#new-api

Comment: You are calling _mongoDb.GetCollection without declaring a class, that should work for you

Comment: @RonBeyer Let me try that

Comment: @faljbour It is giving me a syntax error. The commented out code will work. But don't want to specify a class.

Comment: see my answer, I use it to connect to Mongodb using the C# driver

Comment: my mistake my runtime version is 2.0.5 by the actual release version is 1.8.3, I downloaded 2.0 and yes, it is much different.

Comment: @RonBeyer Cool, the dynamic type worked.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Care to post that as an answer so the question is officially answered? Upvote promised...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MongoDb supports a `dynamic` type in the generic parameter.

```
IMongoCollection<dynamic> _myCollection = _mongoDb.GetCollection<dynamic>("Collection");
```

See http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/what_is_new/#new-api . Example below:

> Support for dynamic.
>
> ```
> var person = new ExpandoObject(); 
> person.FirstName = "Jane";
> person.Age = 12; person.PetNames = new List<dynamic> { "Sherlock", "Watson" };
> await db.GetCollection<dynamic>("people").InsertOneAsync(person);
> ```