# MongoDB Insert Entity vs a BsonDocument using via C# Driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using the .NET MongoDB driver to insert values into my collection in MongoDB .

I noticed when I insert an entity the objects get stored as simple columns like in the second document below where as when I used a BsonDocument to insert documents they get inserted as an object under the _v column in the first document below.

[image]

Can someone explain whats the difference between the two?

Also is it possible to insert the BsonDocument like in the second document via the .NET driver? In my case I have to build the document Dynamically since I dont have a concrete entity to insert with.

Comment: please provide a repo

Comment: Can you provide the code that you use for inserting documents in the collection?

Answer (score 2):

The result you're seeing is related to `dynamic` handling. Mongo driver doesn't know which type you use and save this information in `_t` field. To fix it you just need to create collection based on `BsonDocument` directly like:

```
  var coll = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("coll");
  coll.InsertOne(new BsonDocument("name", "value"));
```

See this [doc](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.13/reference/bson/mapping/polymorphism/)

Comment: Nice answer, I will upvote later. I was also able to `db.GetCollection<dynamic>(...)` and still insert a BsonDocument object without extra _t info, [as described here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/what_is_new/#new-api) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29967516/1175496)

Answer (score -1):

So with the .NET driver:

1. If I insert the bson object directly the document is inserted as an object with column "_v"
2. If I insert the bson object after deserializing it using the BsonSerializer it can be inserted as simple columns in MongoDB.

   ```
            var collection = database.GetCollection<dynamic>(collectionName);
            var bson = new BsonDocument();
            ...
            // Fill bson object
            ...
            collection.InsertOne(bson); // Image 1 
            collection.InsertOne(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(bson)); // Image 2
   ```